# ReplaceAll Google script

Tags: javascript, replace, google-apps-script

I've got a problem, I am trying to use a replace function in JavaScript and I cannot get it to work.
I'm using:

```
var pagename = projectname.replace (" ", "");
```

But it only takes the first space, I wanted to take all the spaces. example:

"My first project 1" = "Myfirstproject1", ie get everything together.

I'm developing the script of google apps.

Thank you.

Comment: How about more information, like what language are you using? REPLACE is very general as a tag. need more info...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! May I refer you to this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 18):

You should try :

```
var pagename = projectname.replace (/\s/g, '');
```

the `g` at the end of the regular expression, is a flag indicating to the replace method that it shouldn't replace only the first occurrence of the space character.

Comment: Sorry, I'm to use Google Apps (script)

Comment: What do you mean by Google Apps ? This is a JavaScript example if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Tks peoples, var pagename = projectname.replace (/\s/g, ''); It's perfect.

Answer (score 9):

You use this code outside other function.

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
        var target = this;
        return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
};
```

Then you can use replaceAll function.
Example :

```
var text = "H e l l o W o r l d";    
text = text.replaceAll(" " , "");
```

Result : HelloWorld

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `replaceAll` is not available in Google AppScript.
You may use `RegExp` version of `replace` to implement `replaceAll`.
If you want to create some kind of generic solution, you need to escape subject from special `RegExp` characters, as symbols like `.^` (and many others) have special meaning in regular expressions.

```
function strReplaceAll(subject, search, replacement) {
  function escapeRegExp(str) { return str.toString().replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9_]/g, '\\$&'); }
  search = search instanceof RegExp ? search : new RegExp(escapeRegExp(search), 'g');
  return subject.replace(search, replacement);
}
```

We may also add this to string class, but I suggest to test if is already here, just in case it may be added in later versions of Google AppScript.

```
if (String.prototype['replaceAll'] == null) { 
  String.prototype['replaceAll'] = function(search, replacement) { 
    return strReplaceAll(this, search, replacement) 
  }; 
}
```

Also, please pay attention, that `$` has special meaning in replacement string in `replaceAll` (JavaScript also work this way). So probably you need additional function `escapeReplacementString` to handle this in case pure text-to-text replace (this function is also useful in JavaScript).

```
function escapeReplacementString(str) { return str.toString().replace(/\$/g, '$$$&'); }
```

So generic text-to-text replace will be like `text.replaceAll(search, escapeReplacementString(replace))`:

```
var text = 'Money is +'; search = '+'; replace = '$& and $$';
console.log(text.replaceAll(search, replace)); // gives you 'Money is + and $' [?!]
console.log(text.replaceAll(search, escapeReplacementString(replace))); // gives 'Money is $& and $$'
```

More: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll

JSFiggle playground: https://jsfiddle.net/r8geycLq/